# SmartGWT Column Chart Type Display X and Y Axis Lables

Tags: bar-chart, smartgwt

I'm displaying a chart (Column chart type) and I want to display two string values as the labels for X and Y axises.

What is the property of the chart to set those values ??
(I'm using SmartGWT version 2.4.0)

```
FacetChart chart = new FacetChart();
chart.setFacets(new Facet("myId", "My Value"));
```

Answer (score 1):

will this help ??

```
  FacetChart chart = new FacetChart();
  chart.setFacets(new Facet("season", "Season"));
  chart.setValueProperty("temp");
  chart.setData(new Record[]{sprRec, sumRec, autRec, winRec});
  chart.setTitle("Average temperature in Las Vegas");
```

taken from http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/chart/FacetChart.html

Comment: thanks, Y axis value is set using the setValueTitle() method.

Answer (score 1):

```
chart.setFacets(new Facet("myId", "My Value"));
```

"My Value" is the x axis title.

For the value field title you can use following:

```
chart.setValueTitle("ABC");
```